# Why is padding right not working?

Tags: css, padding

I want to add padding around the iframe but for some reason I can't get it to apply padding equally around each side.

```
.container {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

```
.content {
padding-top: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

```
iframe {
padding: 20px;
```

}

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="container">

        <iframe width="100%" height="500" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/468897489%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-lEQFX&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>

        </div>
    </div>
```

[Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBEta.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding on the iframe is the same all the way around.  It's the combination of container and iframe whose padding is throwing the iframe to the right further than it should be.

To get this right, you can set the padding on a div containing the iframe, instead of the iframe itself.

https://codepen.io/koohiisan/pen/mjmJNj

```
.container {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
padding-top: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

iframe_container {
padding: 20px;
}
<div class="content">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="iframe_container">
        <iframe width="100%" height="500" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/468897489%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-lEQFX&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I created a div for the iframe and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, its because you have inline CSS on your iFrame, so its ignoring your padding style from your external CSS. Try adding the padding to the inline CSS with the width and height, and it should work.